# java vm options and AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, jvm-arguments

I would like to run my docker container as following:

```
 docker run java \
  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions \
  -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
```

Where should I pass `vm arguments` when writing `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` in cloudformation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same thing at work, you could pass the flags directly in `Dockerfile` as per below.

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```